# Write logs in PHP outside Docker container

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes

I have a task to write logs outside the docker container. It's a bit problem because I cannot save logs inside the container and we decided to use docker pipe. As you maybe know docker provides logs based on pipes inside Linux. The same approach using in Docker PHP-FPM. So my solution is:

```
$rs = popen("cat - > /proc/1/fd/1", 'w');
fwrite($rs, "Test" . PHP_EOL);
pclose($rs);
```

What do you think about it?

Comment: Why not just mount a directory from host machine and write logs there?

Comment: We are using Kubernetes. Of course, we can use volumes, but it's useless a bit to spend money for logs. Kuberenetes provides the solution which accumulates logs from containers.